# How do I use a custom template file?

Tags: 6, theming

I tried using a custom template file for my theme, but using page--testpage.tpl.php (where testpage is the path alias for the page being shown) doesn't work. It just works with page--node--47.tpl.php

How could I fix it?

Comment: I found this: http://drupal.org/node/223440#comment-4114366. Look like you have to use theme_hook_suggestions function for Drupal 7

Answer (score 2):

Read [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656)

> A theme hook suggestions is an alternate template (.tpl.php) file that
>   you have created to override the base or original template file.

The list of suggested template files is in order of specificity based on internal paths. One suggestion is made for every element of the current path, though numeric elements are not carried to subsequent suggestions. For example, "http://www.example.com/node/1/edit" would result in the following suggestions:

page--node--edit.tpl.php

page--node--1.tpl.php

page--node.tpl.php

page.tpl.php

Read [Theming Drupal 6 and 7](https://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7)

If you still want to alter the suggestions its possible with `template_preprocess_page`

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = "page--type--" . $vars['node']->type;
  // likewise you can do 
  // $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = "page".GET-URL-ALIAS-HERE;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work even with force set on specific template
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page--testing';

Comment: This work for drupal 6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338176/custom-page-tpl-php-for-a-drupal-view

Comment: just fix it '__' not '--' :D

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it looks like you're using Drupal 6.  In that case, use a single hypen (not a double) in the name of your template file.  I.e.: `page-testpage.tpl.php` instead of `page--testpage.tpl.php`.

(Use the double hyphen syntax for Drupal 7.)